# libbson help to read data into object C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

i have my unreal project that must read out some BSON document data into a map.

right now i'm able to load that file and print it out with the following code :

```
void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    std::ifstream input( filePath , std::ios::binary );
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});

    bson_t* doc{ bson_new_from_data(buffer.data(),buffer.size()) };
    char *str;
    if( doc != nullptr )
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp,Warning,TEXT( "Success" ));

        str = bson_as_json(doc, NULL);
        
        FString fstr = FString(UTF8_TO_TCHAR(str));
        
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("BSON Output: %s"), *fstr);       
    }
}
```

and this is here is where i want to store it  :

```
class Databases
{
    std::map<std::string,DatabaseBase> _dictionary;

    explicit Databases(const std::map<std::string, DatabaseBase>& dictionary)
        : _dictionary(dictionary)
    {
    }
};
```

so what i'm looking for is to create a new instance of Databases and initialize "_dictionary" with the content of the bson document.

i'm actually looking for this into the libbson document : http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_t.html

but without success...anyone can help me?

thank's in advance

PS: i'm under unreal but i have linked the libbson library

Update:
since i have to provide how my json file looks like, and DatabaseBase looks like

JSON :

```
{
  "_dictionary" : [ {
      "_classID" : "CC00",
      "_dictionary" : [ {
          "k" : "sample_key",
          "v" : ["ACH_00"]
        }, {
          "k" : "sample_index",
          "v" : ["0"]
        }]
    }, {
      "_classID" : "CC01",
      "_dictionary" : [ {
          "k" : "sample_key",
          "v" : ["ACH_01"]
        }, {
          "k" : "sample_index",
          "v" : ["1"]
        }]
    }]
}
```

DatabaseBase :

```
class DatabaseBase
{
public:
    DatabaseBase() = default;

    std::string sample_key;
    int sample_index; 
};
```

Comment: Can you explain how to initialize a `DatabaseBase` object from a JSON document? (ie what is in the JSON document?)

Comment: it is a class that contains some value like integer,string and enum

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is about. You converted the BSON to JSON; doesn't unreal engine support parsing JSON? Alternatively you can consume the BSON directly.

Comment: what i'm looking to do is store the entire document contained in the bson file into _dictionary map. in c# is easy to do, but in C++ no, and it's not weel documented

Comment: We cannot tell you how to convert an arbitrary BSON/JSON value into a `DatabaseBase` without knowing what that type or the mapping looks like. Are you happy with just a generic `Json::Value` type or whatever?

Comment: so, what are you say its that i have to do my own implementation to deserialize my object into it's own class? because DatabaseBase it's just a base class that store different data every time, int..float..string.. so by casting Json::Value i could be able to get my data stored? since it will be a runtime process i'm wondering if it's fast enough

Comment: You already did an expensive network call to retrieve the data. If you're going to access the values just once, dig into the (dynamic) JSON object. If you're going to do these accesses many times, convert into a statically known object once.

Comment: Voting to close this question since you are unable to clarify how a JSON value should be mapped to a DatabaseBase object, which makes the question unanswerable.

Comment: question updated, i hope that is enought know, thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking out [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json):

```
    using nlohmann::json;
    std::map<std::string, DatabaseBase> dictionaries;
    json input = json::from_bson(buffer);
    for (auto& obj : input["_dictionary"]) {
        auto name = obj["_classID"];
        auto key = obj["_dictionary"][0]["v"][0];
        auto idx = stoi(obj["_dictionary"][1]["v"][0].get<std::string>());
        auto db = DatabaseBase{key, idx};
        dictionaries[name] = db;
    }
    Databases dbs{dictionaries};
```

output: (from my debugger)

```
(lldb) p dbs
(Databases) $0 = {
  _dictionary = size=2 {
    [0] = {
      first = "CC00"
      second = (sample_key = "ACH_00", sample_index = 0)
    }
    [1] = {
      first = "CC01"
      second = (sample_key = "ACH_01", sample_index = 1)
    }
  }
}
```